# What is the time complexity in this method?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the complexity of the next method, considering S1 and S2 as O(1) and they don't change any value of any variable.

```
void method(){
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j=i; j<=m; j++) 
        S1; 
        for (int k=t; k>=i; k--) 
        S2; 
    }
}
```

I think that it's `O(n*(m+t))`, is it true?

And can someone explain shortly or send a link about space complexity? I know that it changes if I declare an array inside a method of size n, but not if it's as a parameter, same with lists, is there any other scenario where space complexity changes?

Comment: The space complexity question should really be posted separately, but space complexity is determined by the *additional* memory your algorithm uses, not including the input. Just like time complexity, this will depend on the space complexity of `S1` and `S2`.

Comment: As you wrote the complexity is: O(n*(m+t))

Comment: You can learn about space complexity through any of the top searches that come from google. What chepner said was correct. Also, since you assume that S1 and S2 are constant, you are correct in your runtime assumption, although, depending on if which on is larger, you could simplify to o(nm) or o(nt)

Answer (score 0):

1. Outer loop runs (n-1) times (starts at 1, up to but not incl. n due to i<n).
2. Second loop runs m times.
3. Third loop runs (t-i) times, or really just t.

Add sequential statements, multiply nested ones, and simplify.

```
t(n) = (n-1)(m + (t-i))
=> n(m+(t-i))
t.f O(n(m+t)), or O(n(max(m,t)))
```